# Verify values in Json Object using Rest Assured

Tags: java, json, rest-assured

I want to verify that id: 1 belongs to Tiger Nixon

```
{"status":"success","data":[{"id":"1","employee_name":"Tiger Nixon","employee_salary":"320800","employee_age":"61","profile_image":""}
```

I have been following this document: `https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#json-using-jsonpath`  , this section `body("shopping.category.find { it.@type == 'groceries' }.item", hasItems("Chocolate", "Coffee"));`

Currently I am getting a null pointer exception. I could use some help to come up with a solution. Thanks in advance for your time.

```
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import org.testng.Assert;

public class RestAssuredExample_2 {

    public void getResponse() {
        JsonObject responseObject = RestAssured.get("http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees")
                .then()
                .extract().response().as(JsonObject.class);

        String emp1Name = responseObject.get("data.find{it.@id=='1'}.employee_name").toString();
        Assert.assertEquals(emp1Name, "Tiger Nixon");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RestAssuredExample_2 rest2 = new RestAssuredExample_2();
        rest2.getResponse();
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at HTTPz.RestAssuredExample_2.getResponse(RestAssuredExample_2.java:16)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried to replicate this scenario

```
String responseObject = RestAssured.get("http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees").then().extract().asString();
JsonPath js = new JsonPath(responseObject);
String emp1Name = js.get("data.find {it.id =='1'}.employee_name").toString();
System.out.println(emp1Name);
```

And I get the value for **emp1Name** as "**Tiger Nixon**"

**Difference :**

**Original :** `it.@id=='1'`

**Mine :** `it.id =='1'`

It seems like @ is for XMLPath and not for JSONPath and honestly I wouldn't know about it in detail as well cause I have been using JSONPath only for a very long time :)